# turn circular convolution into linear convolution by zero padding: A special case

Tags: fourier-transform, convolution

We know that, multiplying a kernel and signal spectrum in Fourier domain will lead to a circular convolution and not a linear convolution, so in order to it become linear convolution we must zero pad your signal and kernel before taking the Fourier transform (up to M+N-1 where M is the signal's length and N is the kernel's length). However, I have already known the analytical solution to the Fourier transform of the kernel, while I don't know the analytical form of the kernel. I know that I can inverse discrete Fourier transform $\mathcal{F} \{kernel\}$, then sample and do the zero-padding, but I will lose the advantage of the "analytical form" in this case. Is there any good way for me to turn the circular convolution into linear convolution?

Comment: "in Fourier domain": you mean in *discrete* Fourier domain; I know this reads like nitpicking, but it's usually really important to be sure what you're talking about here; the confusion between *Fourier Transform of a continuous function* and *Discrete Fourier Transform* is the Nr. 1 reason for "my" students having problem when we confront them with OFDM in the fourth semester.

Comment: So, do you know the analytical form of the continous-time Fourier Transform, or of the DFT? That makes all the difference here!

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thanks for the clarification. I know the analytical form of the continous-time Fourier Transform

Comment: Could you please give an example of the Fourier transform of the continuous-time kernel? Is the continuous-time kernel band-limited?

Comment: @OlliNiemitalo 1


I was trying to solve an European option pricing problem using Conv method (https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/8e38/7072b056ea3d63b66d5098fc1221adad0594.pdf). The kernel is a probability density function(PDF) and the Fourier transform of it is called characteristic function, and for a certain class of PDF, its characteristic function is known analytically. You can read page 5 of that paper.

Comment: @OlliNiemitalo I think the PDF is time-limited, so the spectral is not band-limited?

Comment: Looks like they are approximating a part of the calculation ("trapezoidal rule"). I'm not entirely sure which part. The text does not convey their intention clearly.